# Time needed for a UPS to switch from line power to battery?

Tags: ups

What is the average time for a UPS to switch from line power to battery? I now there are some more expensive "inline" UPS which don't have a switching transient, but I want to see if I can use a less expensive unit.

Comment: As far as I can recall, this measure of time is called "transfer time" by UPS vendors.

Comment: Shouldn't a UPS kick in the moment theres a power outage, preventing the clients from even recognizing that there was one (except for state messages etc.)?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you're going to use it for. Transfer time shouldn't be important for most applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the type of UPS. From [Electropaedia](http://www.mpoweruk.com/ups.htm):

> **Off Line or Standby UPS**
>
> These are simple inexpensive systems
>   providing only basic protection. In
>   normal situations the UPS passes the
>   mains power directly to the load. The
>   mains power provides a single DC line
>   which keeps the battery charged. When
>   the UPS detects a voltage too low, it
>   turns on the inverter to power the
>   load from the battery. The system is
>   relatively slow (longer than 4 ms) and
>   the delay between mains power loss and
>   inverter startup can be long enough to
>   disrupt the operation of some
>   sensitive loads. This technology does
>   not normally provide full time power
>   conditioning but it may use a simple
>   filter to clip spikes and electrical
>   noise.
>
> **On Line or No Break UPS**
>
> These are designed to provide a zero
>   transfer time, with better voltage and
>   frequency regulation than that can be
>   achieved by off line and line
>   interactive UPS. In on line systems
>   the mains power is used to provide two
>   DC power lines which feed both the
>   charger and the inverter which is
>   permanently turned on providing the AC
>   power to the application. When the
>   mains fails, the inverter
>   instantaneously draws its DC supply
>   from the battery instead of the mains.
>
> The method by which the AC load is
>   permanently supplied by the system
>   inverter and not the mains is called
>   "double conversion" since the charger
>   provides the AC-DC conversion and the
>   inverter converts the DC back to AC
>   again.
>
> On line systems typically provide full
>   power conditioning, protecting the
>   load from all forms of power
>   disturbances, including brownouts,
>   blackout, transient surges or sags. In
>   the event of a mains power failure,
>   there is no delay or transfer time to
>   backup power. These systems are
>   however more costly and have both
>   higher power consumption, and higher
>   heat generation.
>
> **Line Interactive UPS**
>
> These systems contain an off-line
>   inverter but also use a transformer to
>   supply to the load. In the event of a
>   mains failure the inverter is started
>   and switched to the transformer to
>   provide the output. The transformer is
>   used to provide line conditioning
>   however it also maintains output on
>   its secondary briefly when a total
>   outage occurs increasing the hold up
>   time of the UPS. This results in a
>   break in the output of a few
>   milliseconds or less and is thus
>   faster than a simple off line UPS.

In my office, we have several of the [ES style APC UPS's](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BE550G&total_watts=200). Our building has a diesel-powered generator that comes on within 1-2 seconds after a power loss, and we use these UPS's to cover the period between power loss and the generator turning on. I've gone through their documentation for these models and I can't figure out what type they are. I also use these same UPS's at home and my computers have stayed on during a power loss.

Comment: That APC ES UPS is Standby UPS as described in the product page (search "topology")

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that our SMART-UPS (APC) 1000XLs here at work have a 1/4 cycle time transfer.  So, 1/240th of a second.  Fast enough for all devices I've ever had attached EXCEPT for one.  A Digi C/CON-16 with dual RS-422 over fiber interfaces pulling power from the main unit would reboot on transfer.  Adding secondary power to the fiber modules allowed the unit to survive the transfer time!